# How to display {block number} instead {date value} on Wordpress posts?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info, block, raw-data, website-integration

Ideally, the goal is to show the block number (ie: 782667) instead of the date value (ie: 26 March 2023 4:44PM CT) on all wordpress posts and pages that currently display it.

There's maybe a script we can add to the `functions.php` in the wordpress child-theme currently in user?

Comment: Do you know which plugin you are using for WordPress?  There are [a lot of different plugins](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/tags/blockchain/).

Comment: Ideally we're not using (and we'd prefer to do not use) any plugin, that's why I was asking if a simple `function` in the functions.php file on the active theme could do the job.

But if there's any plugin that allow the `date` to be replaced with the `blocknumber`... could you please share it here?

We did post the [same question in the WP stack](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/414952/how-to-display-block-number-instead-date-value-on-wordpress-posts) too and see if a merge of both knowledges can help. WP users do not know about blockchain and *vice versa*.

Comment: Response to this question has been provided [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/414952/how-to-display-block-number-instead-date-value-on-wordpress-posts/417816#417816)