# There's any open API to gather the blockNumber data?

Tags: api, block

Trying to create a scrip to [convert wordpress posts/pages date and display it as `blockNumber`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/414952/how-to-display-block-number-instead-date-value-on-wordpress-posts) instead. For context, a [similar question also posted on this stack](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/117706/how-to-display-block-number-instead-date-value-on-wordpress-posts).

Do anyone knows if there's any open API or where the `blockNumber` can be retrieved from?

Comment: Similar question was answered in this stack overflow: [Getting Bitcoin's block number in a specific date and hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53788151/getting-bitcoins-block-number-in-a-specific-date-and-hour)
Example: Convert the time of your wordpress post "Thursday, March 30, 2023 3:57:52 PM" to seconds since the UNIX epoch --> 1680191872, add three zeroes to that number --> 1680191872000 and insert it in URL like this: https://blockchain.info/blocks/1680191872000?format=json

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's already answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53788151/

Comment: Response to this question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/414952/how-to-display-block-number-instead-date-value-on-wordpress-posts/417816#417816)